# Compile single C++ file in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I want to compile a single file in c++ using Visual Studio 2010. I created a new file, not a project, and wrote some "hello world" code and I want to compile it and run it. How to do so?
I've searched here and in Google, I got things like F7 or F5 nothing worked.

Comment: @Bart: you can, you can use the development environment command prompts to manually compile (and link) individual source files, and use nmake to make organised builds without an IDE.

Comment: @myself: I'm sure there was a comment from a "Bart" there...

Comment: @dreamlax Yes, there was a comment there. I said "Basically, you don't without a project". I don't use the command prompt for VS very often myself, but each time I have done so it was using a solution or project. You're saying that's not needed? You can purely compile a .cpp? And that would still be from outside the IDE, right?

Comment: @Bart: Yeah, the command prompts are set up so that the compiler and linker are in the `PATH` (and various other environment variables are set too), so you can compile standalone source files.

Comment: aizen - Create a quick_test project, and reuse that the next time you want to do a quick test run.

Comment: @dreamlax Okay, that was more or less what I was going to answer. "Not from within the IDE, but..." Although I do exactly what Bo Persson just suggested myself.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the helpful answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from MSDN to compile standalone C++ files without an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 6.0, you could load up a single CPP file, with a main(), and compile it.  Can't remember if this was taken away in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010, but it's gone.

It used to be easy to fire up a new instance, paste in some test code an just run it.  Now it takes creating or using a dummy project, as others above have noted.

Not hard, just less handy than before.

Answer (score 1):

Probably for simple tests editing your source file in some editor like Notepad or [Metapad](http://liquidninja.com/metapad/) and building from the command line with something like:

**cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo YourSource.cpp**

would be just fine (faster than starting up VS2010 IDE, create new project, etc.)